# Include a file with a different folder

Tags: php

I like to use php-include for the first time to include different partials within my static webpages. My folder structure is something like that:

```
-index.php
-other.php
----production
-------partials
-----------partial1.php
----public
-------images
-----------image1.png
```

And I want to reference the image from my partial1.php. So I try to do

```
<img src="../../public/images/image1.png">
```

but the reference doesn't work and I can add or delete as many "../" as I want, still not working. How else would I define a path to my public-folder and reference to that correctly?

Comment: If you index.php is in the "root" of your site simply use `/public/images/image1.png` to reference that image.

Comment: Your approach is correct from a technical point of view. Take a look at your http servers log files to find what URL the client translates the request to. A cleaner alternative would be to use an absolute path (`/images/image1.png`) as reference and define an `Alias` on the server side configuration for those requests. A ton of benefits if you decouple request paths from the actual physical layout on of the server side file heirarchy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try insert full path:

```
<img src=\"<?php echo @getcwd()."/public/images/image1.png" ?>\" />
```

or add other ../:

```
<img src="../../../public/images/image1.png">
```